# Source for saying seven specific psalms in the cemetery

Tags: tefilla, minhag, tehilim-psalms

What is the source as cited in the ArtScroll Tehillim for saying chapters 33, 16, 17, 82, 91, 104, and 130 of Tehillim in a *bais hachayim* (Jewish cemetery)? Why specifically these chapters and why in this specific order (as opposed to the order in which they appear in Tehillim)?

Comment: S. Indig, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Could you please [edit] in more information about where you came across this custom, prompting you to want to know its source? Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I look forward to seeing you around!

Comment: Please edit where you read or know about this custom. For example, http://www.chevrakadisha.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/prayer_book.pdf has a completely different mix. Psalm 23 seems extremely common, from what I have seen, and I don't see it in your list.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm somewhat surprised that Art Scroll doesn't offer some explanation. I'm particularly surprised that they strayed from the pretty common "minhag" of excluding #23. You tend to see that one almost everywhere else. Does Art Scroll specify when these should be said? I.e. - funeral, unveiling, just visiting or any / all of these occasions?

Comment: I seem to recall a similar custom in which a visitor recites the corresponding letter sections in Tehillim 119 according to the deceased person's name.

Comment: If all else fails and we cannot figure out ArtScroll's source, you can always contact them and ask them from where they learn these psalms should be recited in a cemetery. If anyone would know, they would.

Comment: @ezra I'm somewhat skeptical. Rabbi Zlotowitz who compiled the majority of the Siddurim was recently niftar. He was encyclopedic in his knowledge of these types of items, and, if he didn't know, himself, he knew whom to contact.

Comment: @DanF *Rabbi Zlotowitz **ztz''l** R' Nosson Scherman is still alive though and he might know, being so close to him and also helping in the compilation of the various siddurim and tehillim'lech from ArtScroll.

Comment: I've contacted ArtScroll. I'm currently waiting for a response. Hang tight. :)